# I have a problem building an array of "*" in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a program that contains the following piece of code for constructing an array of asterisks:

```
char array[Length][Height];

for (int count1 = 1; count1 <= Length; count1++)
{
    for (int count2 = 1; count2 <= Height; count2++)
    {
        strcpy(array[count2][count3], "*");
        cout << array[count2][count3];
    }
}
cout << endl;
```

When I attempt to compile the program, I receive the following output:

```
waves.cpp:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
waves.cpp:48: error: initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
```

The 'char*' part of the output lead me to do some reading on pointers, and while I understand the basic principle of them, actually implementing them is proving somewhat difficult (and I guess that's the difference between reading about something and doing it).

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong in this code so I could use it as a worked example, it would go a long way to helping me understand the use of pointers.

Comment: I removed the "pointers" tag as the question technically doesn't have anything to do with pointers. Arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing.

Comment: If the provided snippet is the original code, I would expect another message from compiler like = `error: ‘count3’ was not declared in this scope` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char array[Length][Height];

for (int count1 = 0; count1 < Length; count1++)
{
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < Height; count2++)
    {
        array[count1][count2] = '*';
        cout << array[count1][count2];
    }
}
cout << endl;
```

Note that your code contained off-by-one errors: `count1` and `count2` would go from 1 to Length/Height, which would skip the first byte in the array and write one byte past its size. In C/C++, array indices start at zero and end at length - 1. I corrected the errors in the code above.

`strcpy()` is intended for copying *strings* from one place in memory to another. What you want to do is not to copy a string, but to assign a single char value (which, conceptually, is no different from an int apart from its size*). The C language has no native string type -- instead, it uses continuous blocks of memory that end with a byte that has the value zero (null-terminator). Working with strings in this manner is difficult, painful and error-prone. Since your post is tagged with "c++", I would advise you to use the C++ Standard Library's [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) type when dealing with strings in the future.

* On some platforms, an int might be no larger than a char.

Comment: the_drow: Learn what the hard way? The off-by-one? The difference between strings and characters? Proper string handling in C++? My answer touched upon all these subjects, and I don't see why he would benefit from learning any of this "the hard way". The OP has clearly made an attempt to solve the problem. Failing that, he came here -- and that is perfectly fine.

Comment: You did not explain the character versus string and thus the error message that was generated and why your versoin fixed the message.

Comment: York: My interpretation was that the OP needed help fixing the code. He was clearly on the wrong path with strcpy, and I saw no reason to delve into it further. If you think that my answer is inadequate, feel free to provide one yourself, or expand upon mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'*'` to enclose the character.

Also, use simple assignment operator `=`, for character assignment, as in:

```
array[count1][count2] = '*';
```

with the subscripts `count1` & `count2` running from `0` to `Length-1` & `Height-1` respectively.

`strcpy()` is unneccesary as you are putting together the array character-by-character.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of an array of `char`, but you're trying to copy in a `char*` instead.

```
    array[count2][count3] = '*';
```